# ko.computed property to determine visibility not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In my KncokoutJS ViewModel, I have the follow computed property:

```
self.SelectedUserHasRoles = ko.computed(function () {
  if (self.isLoaded()) {
    return self.selectedUser().roles().length > 0;
  }
  return false;
});
```

And in my HTML, I have the following:

```
<!-- ko if: isLoaded() -->
  <!-- ko if: !SelectedUserHasRoles -->
  <div>
    <p>User has no Roles.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- ko if: SelectedUserHasRoles -->
  <div class="roles-wrapper" data-bind="foreach: $root.selectedUser().roles()">
    <div class="role-token" data-bind="text: Name"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

In my code, I was to say this:

> **If** data from AJAX call has finished loading (*isLoaded is true*), then for the currently selected user, **check and see if he/she has any roles**. **If** yes, then **loop through them** and show them, **if not**, show a bit of text saying 'User has no Roles.'

All seems to work, except for the showing `User has no Roles` text snippet. I've no idea why that isn't showing! I'm putting breakpoints into my computed property and can see that when I select a user with no roles, the expression (in console window) is false, and I'm negating that, so I **should** see that text snippet!

What am I doing wrong? I've created a [screencast](https://www.screencast.com/t/zW7LnlKMB) to make things easier to understand.

Comment: Maybe a CSS issue ie the text is displayed elsewhere?

Comment: Are you sure `self.selectedUser().roles()` is not null?

Comment: nope, when I add a User, I also call the `setCurrentUser(user)` function, and you can [see here](https://www.screencast.com/t/LlWoIh6SnET) that `.roles()` is an empty array which is expected for a newly added user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not binding to a variable but to an expression, you need to add parenthesis here:

```
<!-- ko if: !SelectedUserHasRoles() -->
                               //^^ here
```

See the following snippet

```js
function CreateVM() {
    var self = this;
    this.isTrue = ko.observable(false);
    this.selectedUser = ko.observable();
    this.isLoaded = ko.observable();
    self.SelectedUserHasRoles = ko.computed(function () {
       if (self.isLoaded()) {
          return self.selectedUser().roles().length > 0;
       }
       return false;
    });
}

var vm = new CreateVM();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

var userWithRoles = { roles: ko.observableArray([1,2]) }; 
var userWithoutRoles = { roles: ko.observableArray([]) }; 
vm.selectedUser(userWithoutRoles);
vm.isLoaded(true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!-- ko if: isLoaded() -->
  <!-- ko if: !SelectedUserHasRoles() -->
  <div>
    <p>User has no Roles.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- ko if: SelectedUserHasRoles -->
  <div class="roles-wrapper" data-bind="foreach: $root.selectedUser().roles()">
    <div class="role-token" data-bind="text: $data"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- /ko -->
  SelectedUserHasRoles: <span class="role-token" data-bind="text: SelectedUserHasRoles"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

See [user3297291's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096343/ko-computed-property-to-determine-visibility-not-working#answer-43097922) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

When you want to negate an observable or computed value in a binding, you have to call it explicitly:

```
<!-- ko if: !SelectedUserHasRoles() -->
```

In the case of the `if` binding, there's also the `ifnot` counterpart:

```
<!-- ko ifnot: SelectedUserHasRoles -->
```

---

I think it's useful to understand *why* this is needed, since I see it happening a lot.

You could see the data-bind attribute as a comma separated string of key value pairs. Knockout [wraps each of the values in a function](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/expressionRewriting.js#L130), which it calls the `valueAccessor`.

Essentially, you'll go from:

```
 data-bind="if: SelectedUserHasRoles"
```

to

```
{ 
   "if": function() { return SelectedUserHasRoles }
}
```

`SelectedUserHasRoles` is an observable instance, which evaluates as *truthy*. When you negate this value using an `!`, it will always be `false`.

```js
var myObs = ko.observable("anything");

var valueAccessor =    function() { return  myObs; };
var valueAccessorNeg = function() { return !myObs; };

console.log(valueAccessor());    // Returns the observable
console.log(valueAccessorNeg()); // Always prints false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

The valueAccessor function is passed to the `init` method of a binding. Usually, it is retrieved by [calling](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/ifIfnotWith.js#L8) it, and then [unwrapped](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/ifIfnotWith.js#L9). Because the `unwrap` utility doesn't care about whether you pass it an `observable` or a plain value, you'll **not see any errors when you make this mistake**.

```js
var myObs = ko.observable(false);

var va1 = function() { return myObs; };
var va2 = function() { return !myObs; };
var va3 = function() { return !myObs(); };

console.log(ko.unwrap(va1()));    // false
console.log(ko.unwrap(va2()));    // always false
console.log(ko.unwrap(va3()));    // true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

I hope this small peek under the hood might help you (and others that have made this mistake) to be able to determine when the `()` are needed in the future.

Comment: It's a shame your explanation is not in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html)

Comment: I just knew about this. As what @GôTô said, it will be nice if this is added to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same check for isLoaded() twice, actually

```
<!-- ko if: isLoaded() -->
  <!-- ko if: !SelectedUserHasRoles -->
```

if isLoaded() evalutes to false, your SelectedUserHasRoles() won't even be evaluated.

Comment: but is loaded is true, cause when I put a tester `<h6>boo!</h6>` after the `isLoaded()` check, that shows when I select a newly added user

Comment: Is isLoaded an observable? if not, and SelectedUserHasRoles was evaluated first before isLoaded was true, it might not setup dependency tracking on the selectedUser (as selectedUser() was never called, because isLoaded was false before).

Comment: yep, it is observable. `self.isLoaded = ko.observable(false);` I then set it to true, when my ajax call is a success.

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the actualy code. Maybe your user object you assign to selectedUser() is not yet wrapped in a viewModel? Or you should try <!-- ko ifnot: SelectedUserHasRoles? Best to add a console log in your SelectedUserHasRoles computed to see this check actually makes it into the inner if.