# What is difference between accessing value as function or accessing value directly in knockout js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new to knockout. And I saw following code. I don't know what is difference between them. They both giving same result.

```
<p data-bind="text: FirstName"></p>
<p data-bind="text: FirstName()"></p>
//here FirstName comes from api response
```

Suppose api response is something like this

```
{"FirstName":"ABC"}
```

both of the upper p tag giving the `same output`.
What is difference between that two?

Comment: Due to the way the values are accessed in the bindings, both approaches are effectively the same (assuming `FirstName` was an observable). The only difference is that your first evaluates to an observable while the other evaluates to a value (what was held by the observable). I'd say the general rule of thumb is to not evaluate an observable unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43097922/3297291) I wrote earlier goes into what goes on behind the scenes and why you need the `()` in some cases, and you don't need them in others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine the text value programmatically, it is one of the techniques called

> computed observables

So, when you use **FirstName** it will get the value. You can also get value by calling **FirstName()** and use it for any expression. For example, if the firstName is **xyz** then return **Mr. xyz** else return **Ms. xyz**.

```
FirstName() == 'xyz' ? 'Mr. xyz' : 'Ms. xyz'
```

Refer this for more details - http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html

Comment: can I use FirstName == 'xyz' ? 'Mr. xyz' : 'Ms. xyz' ?

Comment: I don't think you can. 

Let me give you an example - http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LkqTU/

Here try replacing the the text binding in h2 header with this - 
<h2>Hello, <span data-bind='text: firstName() === "Planet" ? "aaa" : "bbb"'>
and then this
<h2>Hello, <span data-bind='text: firstName === "Planet" ? "aaa" : "bbb"'>

You will get what i am trying to say

Comment: why condition will give false always if we use firstName instead of firstName()?