# If Knockout wraps a bounded function expression in a computed, why it doesn't always create a depndency?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This is a follow-up question to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48850849/3002584):

As explained in the above-linked answer:

> When you provide an *expression* for a binding value rather than just a
>   reference to an observable, KO effectively wraps that expression in a
>   computed when applying the bindings.

Thus, I expected that when providing the `changeCity` as a binding expression (it is a function and not an observable), then changing the value on the `input` box would fire the `changeCity` function.

However, as you can see on the first snippet, it doesn't (Nor when binding it as `changeCity()`), but If `changeCity` is declared as a `ko.computed`, it does fire - see the second snippet.

Does it mean that a bounded function and a bounded computed are not completely the same with regard to dependency tracking?

**First snippet - bounded function:**

```js
var handlerVM = function () {
   var self = this;
   self.city = ko.observable("London");
   self.country = ko.observable("England");
   self.changeCity = function () {
     if (self.country() == "England") {
       self.city("London");
     } else {
       self.city("NYC");
     }
   } 
}
ko.applyBindings(new handlerVM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h3 data-bind="text: city"> </h1>
 <span data-bind="text: 'change the country, get out of focus, and nothing will happen...'"></span>
<br/>
<input data-bind="value: country" />
```

**Second snippet - bounded computed:**

```js
var handlerVM = function () {
   var self = this;
   self.city = ko.observable("London");
   self.country = ko.observable("England");
   self.changeCity = ko.computed(function () {
     if (self.country() == "England") {
       self.city("London");
     } else {
       self.city("NYC")
     }
   }); 
}
ko.applyBindings(new handlerVM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h3 data-bind="text: city"> </h1>
<span data-bind="text: 'change the country, get out of focus, and behold:'"> </span>
<br/>
<input data-bind="value: country" />
```

Comment: `ko.applyBindings(handlerVM);` is not correct. You can't just pass the constructor function, you need to actually *create* the viewmodel. `ko.applyBindings(new handlerVM());`

Comment: @Tomalak, thanks, fixed

Comment: *"Does it mean that a bounded function and a bounded computed are not completely the same with regard to dependency tracking?"* - Yes, that's exactly what it means. A plain function has no dependency tracking and it can't have subscribers. If you want a write-only side-effect (like setting an observable value on the click of a button), using a plain function is fine. If you want to calculate a return value from other observables (like filtering an observable array with an input box), using a `ko.computed` is the correct thing to do.

Comment: @Tomalak, I'm left confused, since the answer I linked says exactly the opposite, i.e., since a bounded function is wrapped in a computed, it *does* have a dependency tracking.

Comment: But a "computed" is exactly that: A function, wrapped in `ko.computed()`. As opposed to `self.changeCity = function ...`, which is just a plain function. The latter does not have any dependency tracking, the former does.

Comment: The difference seems to be in how knockout handles in-line expressions defined directly in the markup. I believe the answer you linked was specifically referring to that case. That's just an educated guess though; I don't have a source on that

Comment: You can't bind a computed to an event handler anyway. That's nonsensical. What do you expect to happen in your second code sample? A computed calculates a value, that's its purpose. It doesn't make sense to send click events to it. (Besides, I don't really understand why your buttons are `disabled: true`, that doesn't make any sense either)

Comment: @Tomalak, the expected behavior in both snippets is that once the text in the input box is changed (and the focus is out), `changeCity` is fired (Happens on the 2nd, not on the 1st). The buttons are disabled just to make the point that a button click is not needed to make `changeCity` to fire, but I agree it's confusing, I'll edit it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it that you're not just trying to solve a practical problem, but that you're mostly interested in the "theoretical difference" between passing a `computed` or a plain `function` to a binding. I'll try to explain the differences/similarities.

### Let's start with an example

```js
const someObs =   ko.observable(10);
const someFn =    () => someObs() + 1;
const someComp =  ko.computed(someFn);


const dec = () => someObs(someObs() - 1);

ko.applyBindings({ someObs, someFn, someComp, dec });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>Obs. value: <span data-bind="text: someObs"></span></div>
<div>Computed created in binding: <span data-bind="text: someFn()"></span></div>
<div>Computed created in vm: <span data-bind="text: someComp"></span></div>

<button data-bind="click: dec">-1</button>
```

The example above shows that both `someFn` and `someComp` do the same thing. By referencing `someFn()` in a binding handler's value, you've essentially created a computed with a dependency to `someObs`.

### Why this doesn't work in your first example

You never referenced your `changeCity` method in any knockout related code, which means there'll never be the chance to create a dependency. Of course, you can force one, but it's kind of weird:

```js
var handlerVM = function () {
   var self = this;
   self.city = ko.observable("London");
   self.country = ko.observable("England");
   self.changeCity = function () {
     if (self.country() == "England") {
       self.city("London");
     } else {
       self.city("NYC");
     }
   } 
}
ko.applyBindings(new handlerVM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h3 data-bind="text: city"> </h1>
 <span data-bind="html: 'change the country, get out of focus, and <strike>nothing</strike> <strong>something</strong> will happen...'"></span>
<br/>
<input data-bind="value: (changeCity(), country)" />
```

### Why a regular `computed` *does* work

In your second example, you use a `ko.computed`. Upon instantiating a `ko.computed`, the passed function is evaluated once (immediately) and dependencies to all used observables are created.

If you were to change the `ko.computed` to a `ko.pureComputed`, you'll see your second example will also stop working. A `pureComputed` only evaluates once its return value is actually used and won't create dependencies until then.

### The internals

Knockout [wraps your binding's value in a function](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/expressionRewriting.js#L130) *as a string*. You can read more about this in [an answer I wrote earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43097922/3297291).

We also know that any `observable` that is called inside a binding-handler's `init` method, creates a dependency that calls the binding's `update` method when a change happens.

So, in the example I gave, this is what happens:

1. The `text` binding is parsed
2. The function `function() { return someFn(); }` is passed as a *value accessor* to the `text` binding's `init` method.
3. The value accessor is called to initialize the text field
4. `someObs` is asked for its value and a dependency is created
5. The correct value is rendered to the DOM

Then, upon pressing the button and changing `someObs`:

6. `someObs` is changed, triggering the `text` binding's `update` method
7. The `update` method calls the `valueAccessor`, re-evaluating `someObs` and correctly updating its text.

### Practical advice

To wrap up, some practical advice:

- Use a `ko.pureComputed` when you create a new value out of one or more `observable` values. *(your example)*

  ```
  self.city = ko.pureComputed(
    () => self.country() === "england" 
      ? "london"
      : "nyc"
  );
  ```
- Use a `subscribe` if you want to create *side effects* based on an observable value changing. E.g.: a `console.log` of a new value or a reset of a timer.
- Use a `ko.computed` when you want to create *side effects* based on a change in any of several observables.

Comment: Fantastic, that's the explanation I was searching after.

Answer (score 2):

> the expected behavior in both snippets is that once the text in the input box is changed (and the focus is out), changeCity is fired (Happens on the 2nd, not on the 1st).

Ahhh, now I understand. You are describing what a [*subscription*](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables) does.

First off, rid your mind of DOM events. The `<input>` field does not exist. All there is is your viewmodel. <sup>(*)</sup>

With this mind-set it's clear what to do: React to changes in your `country` property, via `.subscribe()`. The following does what you have in mind.

```js
var handlerVM = function () {
  var self = this;

  self.city = ko.observable("London");
  self.country = ko.observable("England");

  self.country.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    switch (newValue.toLowerCase()) {
      case "england":
        self.city("London");
        break;
      case "usa":
        self.city("NYC");
        break;
      default:
        self.city("(unknown)");
    }
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new handlerVM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<h3 data-bind="text: city"></h3>
<input data-bind="value: country" />
```

---

<sup>(*)</sup> Of course the `<input>` field still exists. But it helps to imagine the view (your HTML) as 100% dependent on your viewmodel. Knockout does all the viewmodel-view interaction for you. It takes care of displaying changes in the viewmodel data, and it takes care of feeding back user interactions into your viewmodel. All you should pay attention to is changes in your viewmodel.

Whenever you feel that you need to listen to a basic DOM event like "click", chances are that you are doing something wrong, i.e. chances are you are missing an observable, or a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).

Comment: Thanks, Tomalak, but it seems I'm still misunderstood. I'm trying to settle what you said (A plain function has no dependency tracking) with the ending of the above-linked answer, quoting: *"since `func` uses the value of the observable [...], KO's change tracking sees and remembers that fact when it computes the computed's value"*.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're not making sense. As per your comment, you want something to happen, and I quote again, *"once the text in the input box is changed (and the focus is out)"*. This is exactly what my code does, and your code doesn't. You don't need any DOM "change" or "click" event to fire for that, and and I still don't understand why you want to bind a computed as an event handler.

Comment: Tomalak, I was trying to ask about *why* some *x* happens on case *a* and not on case *b* with regard to a previous SO answer, and not about *how* to make that *x* to happen. The expected behavior I mentioned is just for adding other details to the *why* question. Your answer doesn't refer to the previous question, and so I don't see how my *why* question is being answered. I take it to my fault for being misunderstood, of course.

Comment: Okay, so as a general approach to asking, please ask questions as self-contained units. It's not useful to require the reader a to read and understand previous question first. Nobody is going to bother doing that.

Comment: That being said, in your first code sample, nothing happens because nothing ever calls the `changeCity` function. That much is clear, I think. In your second code sample, your `changeCity` function is an observable (observables are functions!). Knockout calls this function once when you create the viewmodel, to determine its value (the value is `undefined` because you never return anything). Still, during this function call, knockout notices that you read the value of `country`, so it creates a dependency on `country`. And - lo and behold - when country changes, your observable runs again.

Comment: Change the second codeSample to `pureComputed` and it will no longer work, because knockout does not run pure computeds that don't have a subscriber, so the *initial* run that happens on a regular `computed` (to determine its value) does not happen in a pure computed, therefore no dependency tracking, therefore no magic behavior when `country` changes.