# In a Knockout.js view, when do I call an observable as a function?

Tags: knockout.js

I am having difficulty following this example from the [official documentation for the hasFocus binding](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html)

View:

```
<p>
    Name: 
    <b data-bind="visible: !editing(), text: name, click: edit">&nbsp;</b>
    <input data-bind="visible: editing, value: name, hasFocus: editing" />
</p>
<p><em>Click the name to edit it; click elsewhere to apply changes.</em></p>
```

ViewModel:

```
function PersonViewModel(name) {
    // Data
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.editing = ko.observable(false);
         
    // Behaviors
    this.edit = function() { this.editing(true) }
}
 
ko.applyBindings(new PersonViewModel("Bert Bertington"));
```

My confusion comes from the "editing" observable which has not been declared as a function but is being called in the view like a function with `!editing()` and not like a function with `visible: editing` and `hasFocus: editing`.

I have read the documentation from knockoutjs.com but can't figure out what the rules are for referencing observables from the view. If I have an observable foo when do I reference it in the view as foo() and when do I reference it as foo?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use parentheses in knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996185/when-should-i-use-parentheses-in-knockout)

Comment: [This answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43097922/3297291) explains why the `()` can _sometimes_ be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple explanation: *all observables are functions*. So, in this example, `editing` is actually a function. You have to call (or "unwrap" in KO terms) it to get its current value, and that's why you add the parentheses.

When you pass an observable into one of the default bindings, the binding will actually perform this unwrapping for you (see the [source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/visibleHidden.js) for the visible binding, for example). But when you *negate* an observable's value and want to use that, like you do with `!editing()`, you need to first call it to get its value. The result of `!editing` would just always be `false`, since `editing` is a function and will always evaluate to `true`. Whereas the result of `!editing()` is the negated version of the current value of `editing`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the observable variable as a function [e.g. name() and editing()], when you need to take some actions {e.g. not editing (i.e. !editing()) and change name to upper case [i.e. name().toUpperCase()]} on the current value of the observable variable (i.e. this.editing and this.name respectively).
Refer to: https://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections